# List ALL records of most popular destination

Tags: mysql

In my query I am trying to find the most popular destination and then list all records with that destination.

There is only 1 table called 'orders'
and the destination field is called 'order_destination'

Can't find this particular query anywhere

sample data:

```
Flight Id    Destination
   1           New York
   2           New York
   3           Cuba
```

When I enter the query, it should should show up with both the New York Entries.

I have tried many different queries with no success at all.

Comment: show what you have tried. and explain also in details.

Comment: Please, give us sample data, a table structure, your failed tries etc...

Comment: Please read this and then [edit] your question. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/

Comment: @O.Jones I'm sorry I don't have what I have tried already, as I did not keep a record... I just overwrite what I did and tried again from what I researched. I tried the below answers and still no success. it only showed me 1 new york record and not all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a count  group by order_destination limit 1

```
  select * from from order
   inner join (
     select order_destination, count(*)  my_num from order 
  group by order_destination
  order by my_num desc
  limit 1  ) t on t.order_destination = order.order_destination
```

Comment: Sorry mate, that shows everything but the New York entries

Comment: I get it  . answer updated  with list for most popular

Comment: mate, I used your 2nd edited one... as I re-read the requirements for my assignment, and your second edited answer was actually the right one. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to do that in two steps; first of all find the most popular destination

```
select  order_destination, count(*)
from    orders
group by order_destination
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

then you can use the result of that to filter the original table

```
select  t1.*
form    orders t1
join    (
            select  order_destination, count(*)
            from    orders
            group by order_destination
            order by count(*) desc
            limit 1
        ) t2
on      t1.order_destination = t2.order_destination
```

Comment: okay, so how would I put both of those in one query as I am running queries from php

Comment: You don't need two queries, just run the second one (which already includes the first). My "two steps" approach was just to make clear what's going on.